# use of IsNull with date

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, isnull

I have the following TSQL code:

```
Declare @MyDate datetime

Select @MyDate = ISNULL(T.requireddate, Convert(DateTime, '01/01/2013', 101)) 
from myTable T 
where T.somekey = somevalue

Select @MyDate
```

The output is NULL.  Why isn't it `01/01/2013`?

Comment: Because `DateTime` is `null`, too.

Comment: Hmmm, lots of down-votes. Still trying to understand my error. I'd be grateful for an explanation. Thanks to all.

Comment: What does `SELECT T.RequiredDate FROM ..` return? Do you really get a `NULL` ?? And what's the **datatype** of `RequiredDate` in your table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that select returns any rows?

If that select returns no rows then @MyDate would be null

Try

```
Select T.requireddate, ISNULL(T.requireddate, Convert(DateTime, '01/01/2013', 101)) 
from myTable T 
where T.somekey = somevalue
```

Comment: Ahh. You are correct. That IS the problem, although I fully expected it to return one row.  Thank you, @Blam, for taking the time to help me. Now to investigate where my row went....